# unknown exchange type 'x-delay-message' RabbitMq with MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, schedule, masstransit

I've been installed 'RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin'. and can be see on plugins list of RabbitMq.
[image]

and configured MassTnasit with RabbitMq Using the follow code:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddRabbitMqMessageScheduler();

            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) => 
            {
                cfg.UseDelayedExchangeMessageScheduler();

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });
```

and injected 'IMessageScheduler' interface to my business service and called 'IMessageScheduler.ScheduledPublish<>()'. 
but I got this error: **unknown exchange type 'x-delay-message' RabbitMq with MassTransit**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that version of RabbitMQ, you need the latest version of the plug-in which is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/tag/3.8.9).

I've updated the MassTransit Docker image to the latest as well: [MassTransit/RabbitMQ](https://hub.docker.com/r/masstransit/rabbitmq)

Answer (score 0):

Updated rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange plugin version from 3.8.0 to 3.8.9 resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same issue while using the CloudMQ instance (RabbitMQ managed services).

```
Error: Error 400 (bad_request): unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message'
```

Upon checking the RabbitMQ Instance details from the CloudMQ portal it was found that the plugin "delayed-message" was not installed & post installing the plugin resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you using v3.12.0 recently like me, look at url of plugin that "v" inserted before version number like this:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/v3.12.0/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.12.0.ez

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/3.11.1/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.11.1.ez

Answer (score 0):

I use bitnami/rabbitmq helm-chart and added this plugin to extra plugins on yaml file. But I needed to enable the plugin in the pod. I executed: `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange` and it has been working anymore.