# unknown exchange type 'x-delay-message' RabbitMq v3.8.14 with MassTransit v7.1.8

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354835/unknown-exchange-type-x-delay-message-rabbitmq-with-masstransit/67356207#67356207) with another version of RabbitMQ and delayed-message-exchange plugin.
Environment:
1- RabbitMQ 3.8.14 -version
2- rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange with two versions. first time with -v3.8.9 and next time with v3.8.17.
[although the official note of delayed-message said](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases): This release targets RabbitMQ 3.8.9 or later versions. and latest version(v3.8.17) targets RabbitMQ 3.8.16 and later versions.
3- MassTransit and MassTransit.RabbitMQ packages -version 7.1.8.
[image]

I got this exception: "unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message'".

This environment with a little difference (RabbitMQ 3.8.13 -version) and the same version of MassTransit and 'rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange' correct worked.

but I have to configure with RabbitMQ 3.8.14 -version!.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at how MassTransit [builds the provided Docker image](https://github.com/MassTransit/docker-rabbitmq/blob/master/Dockerfile) to see how the plug-in is installed and configured with the base 3.8.14 RabbitMQ image. It's using the 3.8.9+ version of the plug-in. This image is used for all the MassTransit unit tests/integration tests.

Comment: Well, as I said , My version of the plugin is 3.8.9+ . But I got the exeption: unknown exchange type