# MassTransit with RabbitMQ - getting error of COMMAND_INVALID - unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to create a MassTransist + rabbitMQ project where i can publish a message in a scheduled time. However i am getting the error of unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message when running the schedule send.

below is my setup

[i have enabled the rabbitmq_delayed_exchange plugin 3.12.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbtGe.png)

[masstransit + rabbitmq configuration]

```
services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
        {
            busConfigurator.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
            busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, busFactoryConfigurator) =>
            {
                busFactoryConfigurator.Host(hosts[0],
                port,
                virtualHost,
                    h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(userName);
                        h.Password(password);
                        h.UseCluster(c =>
                        {
                            hosts.ForEach(server => c.Node(server));
                        });
                    });

                busFactoryConfigurator.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
            });

        });
```

[use message scheduler to publish]

```
public async Task SchedulePublish<T>(DateTime deliveryTime, object values, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            await _scheduler.ScheduleSend<T>(new Uri("queue:inventoryservice.schedule_inventory_event"), deliveryTime, values, cancellationToken);
            //await _scheduler.SchedulePublish<T>(deliveryTime, values, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { }
    }
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3efpb.png)

how to solve it?
is there any good example on schedule publish with masstransit + rabbitmq?

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of images.

Comment: ok, i have change the image of my code to text, do you have any idea on this issue?

Comment: See the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354835/unknown-exchange-type-x-delay-message-rabbitmq-with-masstransit?rq=2) - it's your broker setup.